# This code isn't threadsafe - does it need to be?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a class, which, heavily simplified to the relevant parts, looks like this (dummy names):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass {
   private final SomeProvider someProvider;
   private SomeDataStore store = null;

   private SomeDataStore getStoreAttributes() {
      if (store == null) {
          store = new SomeDataStore(someProvider, <other params>)
      }
      return store;
   }
}
```

A teammate commented that the check for `store == null` isn't threadsafe, because the value of `store` could change between threads. However, we're not sure if it'll matter since nothing ever sets the `store` to null, and I don't see a problem with multiple threads trying to set the same `store` to new SomeDataStore(...) because the datastore is read-only from the code.

Are there any issues I'm missing with the thread safety of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You're forgetting that while computers simulate doing things in the order you tell them to, in reality they reorder everything, keeping in mind to *produce the same effect* as if they were not reordering. Produce the same effect, *as far as the current thread is concerned*. Other threads could see your SomeDataStore object partly being created while they skipped the if. And any inconsistant state. You can mitigate that by making store volatile, its accesses won't be reordered then.

Comment: Though it would be better to just initialize your objects at runtime, and then start threads that use them.

Comment: The answers so far haven't mentioned the Java Memory Model. Threads not only have to coordinate critical sections (areas where threads could conflict), but may have to share data between them. Data sharing between threads requires coordination (using `synchronized` and other idioms) not only for sequencing but also to make changes visible to each other. Setting `store = null` is redundant in a member variable. Why not just set it directly to the value needed instead of instantiating lazily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any issues I'm missing with the thread safety of this?

Yes.  At least these:

- if you have an instance of `SomeClass` that is shared between two or more threads, at least one of those threads ever sets the `store` member to a non-`null` value, and any other thread invokes `getStoreAttributes()` on that instance then you have a *data race*. In that case, the behavior of your program is undefined.
- among the behaviors that can be observed in practice with a data race such as this are

  - one or more threads *never* observe the update to `store`
  - different threads observe the update to `store` in orders that seem mutually inconsistent
- Even if you could assume that reads and writes to `store` were atomic, so that there was no data race, you *still* would have the issue that two different threads could both observe `store` to be `null` and enter the `if` block at the same time.  As a result they would each instantiate a new `SomeDataStore`, which the method would return, defeating the apparent purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In the given example, if there are multiple threads calling the method - "getStoreAttributes()", then the "store" instance variable could be initialized twice.
If in your case its fine to initialize the store variable multiple times then it's fine , no need to add any thread safety.
If you don't want to add thread safety features like synchronized block, at least make "store" variable volatile which will ensure that the threads will read it's  latest state from the memory.

But from the name "store" looks like some resource and initializing it multiple times for no reason doesn't seem correct. And you could save that by adding thread safety.
If one thread is initializing the resource, other will wait and use the initialized resource.
You can implement double locking to ensure the same.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should strive to write your code in a way that will make it thread-safe. Now for the long answer: as far as you can tell your code doesn’t have issues right now due to this unsafe operation. Assuming you are a prodigy and have made the right assessment concerning the current situation, by allowing this into your code base you’ve added some form of debt, some piece of code that could easily prove problematic in the future and may create difficult to find bugs. It’s hard to tell but I see you’re trying to create a cached field, there are ways to make this thread safe.